# How to update data on an online database from a local one

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a local database that I handle with Mysql-workbench

I need to occasionally synchronize some data with on online database running on a server (which I could access from a different Workbench tab)

For instance, with DB1 and DB2, I have to update the prices of the items in DB2 with the prices of the items in DB1 where the product ID is the same.

Is there a way to do it just with one command (without creating fake table, exporting them and re-importing them in DB2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the percona tools pt-table-sync . its free and very good

"This tool changes data, so for maximum safety, you should back up your data before using it. When synchronizing a server that is a replication slave with the --replicate or --sync-to-master methods, it always makes the changes on the replication master, never the replication slave directly. This is in general the only safe way to bring a replica back in sync with its master; changes to the replica are usually the source of the problems in the first place. However, the changes it makes on the master should be no-op changes that set the data to their current values, and actually affect only the replica."

here is the manual page: 
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: Thanks!
Isn't there though a way to do it only by the workbench?
That is, to make two databases communicate through a same SQL command...